# Is the bin/ directory for storing binary files?

Tags: scripting, executable, directory-structure, binary

I have seen many tutorials saying that the `bin` directory is used to store binary files, meaning there is only `0` and `1` in the files in that directory.

However, in many cases, I see files in `bin` that are not only `0` and `1`.

For example, the `django-admin.py` under the `xx/bin/` directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django.core import management

if __name__ == "__main__":
    management.execute_from_command_line()
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, a `bin` directory is not for storing only binary files. It's for keeping *executable* files, primarily.

Historically, before scripts written in various scripting languages became more common, `bin` directories *would* have contained mainly binary (compiled or assembled) non-text files, as opposed to source code.  The main thing about the files in `bin` nowadays is that they are executable.

An executable *script* is a text file, interpreted by an interpreter.  The script in your example is a Python script. When you run it, the `python` interpreter (which is another executable file somewhere in your `$PATH`) will be used to run it.

Also, as an aside, a text file is as much a file made up of zeroes and ones as a binary file is.

Answer (score 13):

“Binary files” is the *etymology* of the `bin` directory, but not its current *meaning*. Originally, it was for binary files, as in compiled programs — files containing machine code that could be loaded into memory and executed as code. But quickly it came to contain any program that could be executed, whether this program was machine code or a script that is interpreted by some other program. Conversely, files containing machine code that cannot be executed directly is not stored in `/bin`, but in `/lib` (for [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing))).

Answer (score 4):

From the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/ch03s04.html):

> /bin contains commands that may be used by both the system administrator and by users, but which are required when no other filesystems are mounted (e.g. in single user mode). It may also contain commands which are used indirectly by scripts.

So, in short, it contains essential program executables. Other folders containing non-essential programs can be /usr/bin, /usr/local/bin etc.